# Dreamspark Extended Access Guarantee Key for Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7

I have a Extended Access Guarantee (24months) Key for Windows 7 that i got from DreamSpark.

Does that mean that I can't install Windows again with this key after 24 months even if I stil have it down on paper, 
or does it mean that I can't ASK for that key again on DreamSpark website?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The latter. You have 24 months to access the key on the DreamSpark website. This is just a convenience measure and it is assumed that you would have copied the key elsewhere by the time your access expires.